# document.cookie prints long string value

Tags: javascript, cookies

I create a cookie like so:

```
document.cookie="colour=red; expires=Thu, 31 Jan 2015 12:00:00 UTC; path=/todoPage";
```

In another section of my code I do:

```
console.log(document.cookie):
```

I would like to get the **name/value** info, instead my console prints a horribly long string value, ideas?

Comment: Try doing something like cookies = document.cookie.split(';'), and then parse with cookies[0]?

Comment: Is that what cookies[0] returns? Then try doing cookies[0][0]